# How to place content after Bootstrap slider with position absolute

Tags: jquery, html, css, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

This is my project:

http://boltardesign.ro/gj/

I have a bootstrap carousel with positon absolute and z-index -1. I want to place immediately after carousel a div, i don't know and i didn't find any solution how to do this.

For a easy undersand of the problem click on the link with the project.

sry my english and thank you very much !

Answer (score 0):

Remove position absolute from carousel and assign absolute property to your navbar header section. It will definitely work.

Comment: Thank you ! It's working, I can not believe I have not thought at this.